# How to pass @MockBean to an internal function call from a JUnit?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I need to write unit tests for a Spring Controller class.

The setup is like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyCustomController {    
    @Autowired
    private MagicWriter magicWriter;

    @Autowired
    private MagicUpdater magicUpdater;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postMagicMethod(@RequestParam(name = "SomeParam") String param1) {
        var magicHandler = new MagicHandler(magicWriter, magicUpdater);

        return magicHandler.doSomeMagic();
    }
}
```

From my JUnit test, I need to use @MockBean for magicWriter and magicUpdater class.
So far I could not find anything constructive.

Here is my Unit test

```
@SpringJUnitConfig
@WebMvcTest(value= MyCustomController.class)
public class MyCustomControllerTest {


    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private MagicWriter magicWriter;

    @MockBean
    private MagicUpdater magicUpdater;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Configuration
    static class Config {
        @Bean
        MyCustomController dispatchController() {
            return new MyCustomController();
        }
    }
    @Test
    void basicTest() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        // Added some http headers

        String uri = "/";

        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.request(HttpMethod.POST, uri, headers);
        MvcResult result =  mockMvc.perform(request).andReturn();
        assertThat(result.getResponse().getContentAsString()).isEqualTo(expected);
    }
}
```

Comment: Testing controllers is a standard task in each Spring Boot testing tutorial. Show us what you’ve already tried. Then someone might be able to help you out.

Comment: Hi @johanneslink 
Added the UT above. Please have a look.

Comment: I'm probably missing something very naive.

Comment: Oh, you've newed your bean.  That's a big no-no.  You can't be doing that if you're trying to go through Spring.  You don't *have* to use the Spring context if you just new your instance up with mock objects instead, and I've found that to be easier to test in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `@Autowired` parameters to be constructor based and not field-based.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyCustomController {

    private MagicWriter magicWriter;
    private MagicUpdater magicUpdater;    

    @Autowired
    public MyCustomController(MagicWriter magicWriter, MagicUpdater magicUpdater) {
        this.magicWriter = magicWriter;
        this.magicUpdater = magicUpdater;
    }
    // ... rest of your code
}
```

Then in your test, you just `new` an instance of this class with your mocks passed in.  You're already resigned to using mock beans, so you don't need to whole Spring Context to come along.

```
// Unit test code example

    MyCustomController testObject;
    MagicWriter magicWriterMock;
    magicUpdater magicUpdaterMock;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        magicWriterMock = mock(MagicWriter.class);
        magicUpdaterMock = mock(MagicUpdater.class);
       
        testObject = new MyCustomController(magicWriterMock, magicUpdaterMock);
    }
```

Comment: But following this approach, I'm not able to construct the Controller in UT. Please check the UT I have added now in the post above.

Comment: I see what you did.  I can revise my answer.  It is trivial to accommodate this approach in a unit test.

Comment: You should be able to use mockbeans in @Bean method as parameter and then pass them to constructor.